# WKWebView get NSURLRequest for internal links click after page load finished

Tags: ios, ios8, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView with loadRequest method swizzled to set custom request (as it in tutorial like [here](http://floatlearning.com/2014/12/one-webview-to-rule-them-all/)

But when internal links followed, loadRequest not called, so in finish load I can get only request which was placed early exactly in loadRequest method, it is obvious.

Now I check in decidePolicyForNavigationAction if navigation action type is WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated and then set NSURLRequest to WKWebView request property directly.

The question is - how to intercept internal links was clicked to set WKWebView request custom property internally.

Just in case implementation in WKWebView category

```
- (void) setRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(request), request, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

I have to NSURLRequest to be present in WKWebView and process it in didFinishNavigation logic.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391866/810466